# Creating a graph with Code Iris in IntelliJ throws NullPointerException for one project but not another

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I installed the Code Iris plugin the other day and successfully ran it on one of my larger Java projects without issue. When I tried to run it on a different, smaller project it fails to do anything and just causes an IntelliJ error with the stack trace below. I can switch back to the working project and create its graph again, so it doesn't seem to be a session issue.

> null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at info.klewitz.bigproject.graph.NewIdeaGraphCreatorFactory$StatefulImpl.init(NewIdeaGraphCreatorFactory.java:122)
>           at info.klewitz.bigproject.graph.NewIdeaGraphCreatorFactory$StatefulImpl.run(NewIdeaGraphCreatorFactory.java:95)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:902)
>           at info.klewitz.bigproject.idea.action.NewGraphCreationService$BackgroundableGraphCreator.run(NewGraphCreationService.java:65)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have no idea how to start debugging this. I've tried the obvious things, like restarting the IDE and re-installing both Code Iris and its dependency, PlantUML.

I assume there's something in my project that Code Iris doesn't like, but I've tried running "Create Graph" on just a single module at a time and got the same result.

I'm hoping someone might have some insight into this plugin and know more about what it likes and doesn't like.